# Using AM-GM inequality to prove

Tags: proof-explanation

prove that $$x^4 + y^4 + z^4 \geq xyz(x+y+z)$$

This AM-GM inequalities are seriously stumping me. I'd appreciate a full proof and explanation and hints for proving other inequalities like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use: $$a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca$$
Proof:$$2(a^2+b^2+c^2)\ge 2(ab+bc+ca) \Leftrightarrow$$
$$\Leftrightarrow(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\ge0$$

Then 
$$x^4+y^4+z^4\ge x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2\ge xy^2z+x^2yz+xyz^2=$$
$$=xyz(x+y+z)$$

Comment: how did the x^2 change to xz?

Comment: we use double $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca$

Then $$x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2 \ge xy^2z+yz^2x+x^2yz$$

Answer (score 2):

AM–GM is invoked in two steps as follows:

$\begin{array}{rcl}x^4+y^4+z^4 &=& \dfrac{x^4+y^4}2+\dfrac{y^4+z^4}2+\dfrac{z^4+x^4}2 \\\\ &\ge& x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2 \\\\ &=& \dfrac{x^2y^2+y^2z^2}2+\dfrac{y^2z^2+z^2x^2}2+\dfrac{z^2x^2+x^2y^2}2 \\\\  &\ge& xy^2z+yz^2x+zx^2y \\\\ &=& xyz(x+y+z)\end{array}$

Answer (score 0):

The inequality is equivalent to ( by expanding RHS) 
$$ x^4 + y^4 +z^4 \ge x^2yz + y^2xz + z^2xy$$
By AM-GM

$$ x^4+x^4 +y^4 +z^4 \ge 4(x^8y^4z^4)^\frac{1}{4} = 4x^2yz$$
$$ y^4+y^4 +x^4 +z^4 \ge 4(y^8x^4z^4)^\frac{1}{4} = 4y^2xz$$
$$ z^4+z^4 +x^4 +y^4 \ge 4(z^8x^4y^4)^\frac{1}{4} = 4z^2xy$$
Adding them up we get

$$4(x^4 +y^4 +z^4) \ge 4(x^2yz+y^2xz + z^2xy)$$
$$ x^4 +y^4 +z^4 \ge x^2yz+y^2xz + z^2xy $$